# ruby datamapper can't save to database

Tags: ruby, database

I have a database schema like that

```
DataMapper.setup :default, "sqlite://#{Dir.pwd}/image.db"
class Image
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id       , Serial
    property :url , String,unique: true
    property :desc    , String,unique: true,default: "empty"
end
DataMapper.finalize.auto_upgrade!
```

Then i have a loop like this

```
links.each do |link|
  puts link
  if Image.all(:url=>link).empty? == true
    img=Image.create(:url => link)
    puts "Cannot save to database "if img.saved? == false
  end
end
```

I want to add a link when it is not already in a database. I run the script and always get cannot save to dabase. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.
Edit: I add to my code

```
DataMapper::Logger.new($stdout, :debug)
```

and there was no insert queries only selects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared :desc property to be unique and set default value to "empty" and in your code example you're creating Image without specifying :desc which results in uniqueness validation failure, that's why your images aren't saved. You can either remove unique option from :desc property declaration or make sure to provide unique value for :desc when creating images.

Also, to make your code more verbose so you could see any validation errors try this:

```
links.each do |link|
  image = Image.new(:url => link)

  if image.save
    puts "Image saved"
  else
    puts "Failed to save image: #{image.errors.inspect}"
  end
end
```

Please note that to use validation errors you need to require 'dm-validations' gem.

Comment: You can ask [Datamapper](http://datamapper.org/docs/create_and_destroy.html)  to raise exceptions on error: `Image.raise_on_save_failure = true`

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean you get "cannot save to database"?

You can try something like this and see if it works a bit better:

```
links.each do |link|
  if Image.first(:url => link)
    p "image exists"
  else
    if Image.create(:url => link) 
      p "Image succesfully saved"
    else
      p "could not save image"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: When my script finish the database is still empty. According to documentation "If the creation was successful, #create will return the newly created DataMapper::Resource. If it failed, it will return a new resource that is initialized with the given attributes and possible default values declared for that resource, but that’s not yet saved. To find out wether the creation was successful or not, you can call #saved? on the returned resource. It will return true if the resource was successfully persisted, or false otherwise." And there is why I check saved? because my database is still blank